# Reload page after submit in iframe (javascript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, submit, reload

I have a page with an iframe. In the iframe there’s a submit button. When I click the submit button I want the parent window to be updated.
This is what I have done so far, and it works (the javascript is located in the parent window):

```
var myFrame = $('iframe');
myFrame.load(function() {
myFrame.contents().find('#publish').click(function() {

  myFrame.load(function() {
    location.reload();
  });

});
});
```

The code works. But I find the reload of the iframe unnecessary. **Is there a better way to detect when "submit" is completed?**

(I can’t reload the page only by “onclick” or relay on any delay. I must be sure that the submitting of the form is finished)

Comment: parent window to be updated? or parent window to be reloaded? what is the update?

Comment: How do you solve this in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `publish` is unique you can simply do so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#publish').live('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     //Do whatever you want here
   });
});
```

Notice the `live` will bind the even to `publish` link at runtime.

Comment: Hi Naveed, you missed "});". But I can't see how this function will help me submit the form and reload the page. I want a function to detect when submit is sent.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the form submission return a block of js:

```
<html>
<script>
 window.parent.document.jQueryFunction();
</script>
</html>
```

or, if you're open to plug-in, you could use the ajaxSubmit() method of [the jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api).

```
$myFrame.contents().find('form').ajaxForm({
  success: function() {
     // update parent
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#publish").click(function() {
    $('#inputs').ajaxSubmit({
        success:function(){
            //alert("Reload called");
            parent.location.reload();
        }
    });
 });
```

This worked.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is no specific reference to Ajax in the question. It may be also a standard html form submit.