# Reload parent page after submit in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have the same issue as in this question. (which has no correct answer, I just test all of them):

[Reload page after submit in iframe (javascript/jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695380/reload-page-after-submit-in-iframe-javascript-jquery)

What I need is very well explained there.

I have a button in a form, all this inside an `iframe` (same domain) **and I need to reload the parent page**, just after the iframe has made the whole submit process, I do not want to "cut" it or interrupt it.

---

**UPDATE:**
I kept searching and I found this. But I can't understand the code in the correct answer, is that for `asp`? I'm on `PHP`.

[Reload page after submit in iframe (javascript/jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695380/reload-page-after-submit-in-iframe-javascript-jquery)

http://dotnetspidor.blogspot.mx/2011/07/refresh-parent-page-partially-from.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once the form has been submitted in the iframe

```
<form method="POST" action="getForm.php">
```

The page reloads into getForm.php, and in that file you do:

```
<?php

    $input = $_POST['input'];
    // process form and do your stuff etc

    echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
    echo "<head>";
    echo "<title>Form submitted</title>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.location.reload()</script>";
    echo "</head>";
    echo "<body></body></html>";

?>
```

and that would reload the parent page after the form has submitted, now the only question is, why are you submitting through an iFrame if you're going to reload the parent page anyway.

Comment: good thinking!! simple solutions are the best.. but reload() need to be condition on posting right. thanks

Comment: Answering your question, this iframe upload a image using some controller for other page, in the parent page there is an image, that must be "updated" after the post in the iframe.. thats why

Answer (score 7):

all that you need to do is add the below line,

```
window.parent.location.reload();
```

at the end of the function that is called `onclick` of your submit button.

Comment: The same answer is already provided and accepted. What is new in this answer?