# Refreshing a page after posting data through an Iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

I had to use an iframe to stop the page from reloading before the action was completed. However, I need it to refresh after the action is taking place. I tried two methods for this, refreshing the page and redirecting to the same page.

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn']) {
   //Action
   location.reload(); 
  //I also tried 
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

HTML:

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" border="0px solid white" style="display:none" name="iframe1" id="iframe1"></iframe>

        <form action="index.php" method="post" target="iframe1">
```

Thanks for your help. All input is appreciated.

Comment: and how you submitted the form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload parent page after submit in iframe ( javascript/jquery )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507015/reload-parent-page-after-submit-in-iframe-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @AmitGaud I have edited my post to include that